# $\exp (\boldsymbol{A} x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n !} \boldsymbol{A}^{n}$ (math and python)

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

The exponential function for $m \times m$ $A$, is defined by

$$\exp (\boldsymbol{A} x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n !} \boldsymbol{A}^{n}, \: x\ge0$$

and $A$ is a sub-intensity matrix or intensity matrix. $x$ is a scalar.

How do I calculate the convergence?

I have to write a function in Python which calculates $\exp(Ax)$ numerically. So I guess I have to know how to calculate the convergence, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Is it admissible to use `scipy.linalg.expm`? At least you can use this function to test your results against.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate the convergence"? Decide when to stop summation?

Comment: @LutzLehmann only for doing some tests.

Comment: @Damien yes, but I think Lehmann have given me a good idea.

Comment: The exponential series is well-known to converge for all complex $x$. (Because the numerators grow by constant factors $x\boldsymbol A$ while the denominators grow by growing factor $n$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the point on where $n>\|A\|\,|x|$ the terms of the series become smaller, for $n>2\,\|A\|\,|x|$ with a factor $\frac12$ and increasingly faster.

---

More efficient methods for the matrix exponential use the eigen decomposition of Jordan normal form of $A$, $$A=U(D+N)U^{-1},$$ $N$ nilpotent, $N^m=0$, and commuting with the diagonal matrix $D$. Then $\exp(Dx)$ is trivially computable as the diagonal matrix with the exponential of the diagonal elements. In total
$$
\exp(Ax)=U\left(\exp(Dx)\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}\frac{x^n}{n!}N^n\right)U^{-1}
$$
is then a finite computation, without any concerns for convergence.

---

The most common procedure to evaluate an analytical function $f$ on a matrix is to compute its eigenvalues, reduce this list to one of unique eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ with multiplicities $m_i$, then compute an interpolation polynomial $p$ with $p(\lambda_i)=f(λ_i)$ and $p^{(k)}(λ_i)=f^{(k)}(λ_i)$ for $1\le k<m_i$. Then $f(A)=p(A)$ can be computed in a finite number of steps, and the question of convergence is reduced to the question of computation of eigenvalues.

Comment: Given $A$, is there some functions in Python which I can use for calculating $U,U^{-1},D$ and $N$ ?

Comment: how about LU decomposition?

Comment: `numpy.` or `scipy.linalg.eig` computes `D` and `U`, you would to have manually construct $U^{-1}$ and $N=U^{-1}AU-D$. Multiple eigenvalues are numerically unstable, so in general $N$ will be zero, but then $U$ might be ill-conditioned. I could not find a function in `scipy` that proceeds according to a variant of the QR-algorithm where $U$ would be orthogonal or hermitean.

Comment: No to $LU$, you need a conjugation, as only then you get $p(QBQ^{-1})=Qp(B)Q^{-1}$ for polynomial or analytical $p$, with the idea that $p(B)$ is easier to compute than $p(A)$ where $A=QBQ^{-1}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "construct U^-1" manually?

And for the rest of your first comment: So it is not possible to implement this in python according to you ? 

btw, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I mean you have to use one of `np.matrix(U)**(-1)` or `np.linalg.inv(U)` or `N=np.linalg.solve(U, A.dot(U))-D`. And yes, you can implement this, but do not be surprised if in some rare cases the accuracy suffers.

Comment: Sorry. I just got a bit confused. Which commands do I use for calculating $D$ and $U$ in Python? And does $U$ have a name?

Btw, I expect that the accuracy will suffer.

Comment: Regarding the first two lines in your answer: "From the point on where $n>\|A\||x|$ the terms of the series become smaller, for $n>2\|A\||x|$ with a factor $\frac{1}{2}$ and increasingly faster.". 

Which use does this have when implementing $$\exp (A x)=U\left(\exp (D x) \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} \frac{x^{n}}{n !} N^{n}\right) U^{-1}$$ in Python?

Comment: `d,U=scipy.linalg.eig(A); D=np.diag(d)`. Now identify clusters of eigenvalues in `d`, replace those clusters in `d` by their center, orthonormalize the blocks of columns of `U` according to the identified clusters, compute `N=np.linalg.solve(U, A.dot(U))-D`. Then `N` will not exactly be nilpotent, but the defect will be proportional to the maximal cluster radius. Powers of $N$ will eventually converge very rapidly to zero.

Comment: The question of a block decomposition $A=U^{-1}BU$ according to eigenspaces that is better than Schur, less than Jordan, with a well-conditioned $U$ is not well-treated in python.

Comment: I will work in that! Thanks!